# AngularJS - how to show an alert when the length of an array is zero and hide the default behavior?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am working with angular and I am showing a little loading circle which disappears once the content is loaded. that circle is just a CSS class that I am calling from my html only the 1st time that the page load, I am doing it this way:

actually the circle has to classes: `.circle` and `.loader` within circle  ...

```
<div ng-hide="lineItems.length" class="circle">
 <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

as you can see below there is a promise with an `if` which says that if linesItems.length is zero then show myModal. everything is working properly but the loading circle still shows up, what I need to do is completely remove that `.circle` and `.loader` once the condition inside the `if` is reached.

```
.then(function(lines) {
  $scope.lineItems = lines;
  if ($scope.lineItems.length === 0) {
   myModal.show();
   console.log('I AMN EMPTY');
  }else {
   loaderAlert.hide();
  }
 }
```

someone says that I have to use an $scope variable but I do not have an idea of how to do it, I am new to Angular, is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start your promise, set a flag to state you are currently loading. Then when loading finishes, set the flag to false. Use this with ng-class or ng-if to make the appearance of the circle conditional.

```
function doStuff(){
    $scope.loadingIsHappening = true;
    myService.getStuff().then(function(){

       // your processing here

    }).finally(function(){
        $scope.loadingIsHappening = false;
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
 <!-- ng-if removes from DOM, while ng-hide modifies CSS display to none-->
<div ng-if="loadingIsHappening == true" class="circle">
    <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you give me a little example of how to do that?

Comment: can you help me thru the chat? I can not achieve what I want

Comment: just go to StackExchange on top left, open it, there says chat blog log out